# How to access a value from within a .then promise?

Tags: javascript

I am doing the following:

```js
fetch("someurl")
.then(data => {return data.json()})
.then(resp => console.log(resp));
```

Now, usually i do the operations on resp from within the .then function, but would it be possible to assign resp to a variable, or at least store it somewhere so i can retrieve it in another function?

Example:

```js
let thedata;

fetch(URL).then(res => {
    return res.json()
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data[0].category); //helloWorld
    thedata = data[0].category 

});


console.log(thedata);

function printsomething()
{return thedata}
```

Now thedata is going to be undefined, and i can't use the function printsomething without having it inside the `.then()` function.

This is what i meant by my question.

Comment: Call the other function from inside the `.then()` callback and pass the value(s) to it.

Comment: yes - but then when using this "other variable" you won't know when the fetch has finished - so, I said yes, but I meant no

Comment: Yeah i was thinking that would be my only option. I thought i could do something with a promise to be able to use it freely somewhere else in the code

Comment: Could you show us in which way you would like to use `resp`? There are ways to do what you want I think, we just need to be sure on how exactly you intend to do it.

Comment: @HannaH You can store the promise itself in a global variable, and use it (asynchronously) whenever you need the value

Comment: *I thought i could do something with a promise to be able to use it freely somewhere else in the code* - yes, you can

Comment: question updated, hope you understand what i mean, im bad at explaining things

Answer (score 1):

By assigning the `fetch` Promise chain to a variable, you can then call `.then` on that variable from multiple locations, though that's somewhat odd to do:

```
const prom = fetch("someurl")
  .then(res => res.json());
prom.then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
// Separately:
prom.then((data) => {
  console.log(data.foo);
});
```

In most cases, it would make more sense to use your original strategy of putting everything inside a single `.then` after `res.json()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that - but then you will need to track whether the async function has returned a value, which may be as simple a checking whether the value is defined. The variable could be in global scope, or a field in some object you import. But by not having the code that requires it called from within the `then`, it means wrapping use of that variable in a check, and handling the possibility it hasn't been set yet. Whether or not that is a good idea depends on context - best to avoid it if you can, but it's a pattern I have used on occasion.

Answer (score -1):

No matter how you handle it you will need to either check or wait for the value so it's best to use it within the `.then()`

While it can be done if you need the variable outside of the `.then()` I think async/await is  cleaner/easier to manage the flow by awaiting functions till they finish in the same way that `.then` would and ensuring your variable is available (you should still validate):

```js
const someAPI = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
let data = null

const fetchFunc = async () =>{
  const response = await fetch(someAPI)
  data = await response.json()  
  // use data
}

const asyncFunc = async () => {
  await fetchFunc()
  console.log(data);
  //use data
}

asyncFunc()
```